# Rails Stripe Checkout Error - Couldn't find AddOn with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I can't seem to understand the error. How do I get the `stripe_checkout` action to receive the specific `AddOn.find(1).price`?

add_ons_controller.rb:

```
  def stripe_checkout
    @add_on = AddOn.find(params[:id])
    @amount = @add_on.price
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                    :amount => @amount * 100,
                    :currency => "usd",
                    :source => params[:stripeToken],
                    :description => "Test Charge"
    )
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created a charge"
    redirect_to '/add_ons'
  end
```

add_ons/index.html.erb:

```
<% @add_ons.each do |add_on| %>
<%= add_on.title %>
<%= add_on.category %>
<%= add_on.description %>
<%= form_tag('/stripe_checkout',{method: :post}) do %>
<script class="stripe-button" data-amount="<%= add_on.price * 100 %>" data-currency="USD" data-email="customer@example.com" data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>" src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What are the parameters being received by the action?

Comment: sorry but i dont understand what you mean by parameters being received by the action.

Comment: def add_on_params
      params.require(:add_on).permit(:title, :description, :benefit, :category, :price, :completed_on)
    end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass an `id` to the form_tag helper:

```
<% @add_ons.each do |add_on| %>
  # some code here
  <%= form_tag('/stripe_checkout',{method: :post}) do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :id, add_on.id %>
  <script class="stripe-button" data-amount="<%= add_on.price * 100 %>" data-currency="USD" data-email="customer@example.com" data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>" src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js">  </script>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Now I get this error instead..

Couldn't find AddOn with 'id'={:value=>1}